# Regex to select only the URLs that don't end with a comma

Tags: java, regex

Could someone help me to write a Regex to match only the URLs which does not have a Comma in it. Also, an explanation on how it works would be grateful.

Example-

1.) `https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/a-way-home/id982665320?mt=11`

2.) `http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/dont-turn-around/id981698737?mt=11,`

The regex I'm using:

```
.*//(itunes).apple.com/(us)/(book).*id([0-9]+).*
```

Output expected -

```
itunesusbook981698737
```

My regex should work only with the first URL and not with second.

Answer (score 0):

```
\/(itunes).apple.com\/(us)\/(book)\/.*\/id([0-9]+)[^,]*$
```

This is your original regex, fixed (there were typos I think) and disallowing commas after the id (or, allowing anything except commas right up to the end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

You can look arounds as

```
^(?!.*,).*(?<=id)(\\d+)
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `(?!.*,)` Negative look ahead. Ensures that the string doesn't contain any `,`
- `.*` Matches anything zero of more times
- `(?<=id)` Positive look behind. Ensures that the digits in the following pattern is presceded by `id`
- `(\\d+)` Matches one or more digits. Captured in group 1

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mD9gV7/1)

**Example**

```
String str1 = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/a-way-home/id982665320?mt=11";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*,).*(?<=id)(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);

if ( matcher.find() )
    System.out.println("itunesusbook"+matcher.group(1));
    // Output
    // => itunesusbook982665320
```